# Fibonnacci sequence in pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I was looking at this and trying to figure out how the Fibonacci is implemented here?

```
public int fibonacci(int x) {
    if (x==1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (x==2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2)
    }
}
```

I'm showing this sequence as the correct sequence.

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
```

The problem is on the `5` iteration I'm getting `7`

```
(5-1) + (5-2)  = 4 + 3
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: looks like someone is studying data structures and algorithms .. ;)

Comment: (5-1) + (5-2) = 4 + 3 this is wrong you got f(5-1) + f(5-2) = f(4) + f(3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `fibonacci(5 - 1) + fibonacci(5 - 2)`, which is the previous two numbers in the sequence (`5` and `3`), not `(5 - 1) + (5 - 2)`.

Also, there is an error in your code, `if (x=2)` should use `==` instead. But I assume that you introduced that when you wrote to Stack Overflow, or I don't think you would be getting the sequence you're getting.

Comment: @Frank: He uses `==` two lines above `=` for the same semantics.

Comment: Yeah that was a type error..  I really was trying to focus on the iteration piece on how "8" is achieved because I was fine until then.   Counting the sequence makes sense but I think I'm missing something with the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are missed that you have:

```
fibonacci(5-1) + fibonacci(5-2) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)
```

Instead of **not** equals:

```
(5-1) + (5-2)  = 4 + 3
```

Your function is correct but slow for big numbers.